# Keep getting that Rate is not defined

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having some strange problem.
When I run the python program I get an error that Rate is not defined:

```
line 30, in EncoderNodeLeft
    rate.sleep()
NameError: name 'rate' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
import time
#import ASUS.GPIO as GPIO
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from nav_msgs.msg import Path
from std_msgs.msg import Int16


class EncoderNodeLeft:

    def __init__(self,encoder):
        self.tick = 0
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher("lwheel", Int16, queue_size=1000)

    def tick_callback(self,channel):
        self.tick += 1
        if self.tick > 32766:
            self.tick = 0
        self.pub.publish(self.tick)

    def run(self):
        #GPIO.add_event_detect(self.encoder, GPIO.RISING, callback=self.tick_callback)
        rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            
            rate.sleep()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        rospy.init_node("encoder_node_left")
        encoder = 224
        encoder_node_left = EncoderNodeLeft(encoder)
        encoder_node_left.run()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        rospy.loginfo("There was an exception in encoder_node_left")
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311939/keep-getting-that-rate-is-not-defined/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2019-01-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:
Both `tick_callback(..)` and `run()` are functions, not methods of class `EncoderNodeLeft`: they are missing the `self` argument. So `self.tick` (in the cb) will fail fi.

Not saying that is necessarily the cause, but it's a potential problem in any case.

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-04**:
@gvdhoorn yes you are right, stupid mistake. But this is not a cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some Python indentation problems I guess. I rewrote everything and it worked, Lol.

---

Originally posted by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) with karma: 361 on 2019-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:
Good to hear you fixed your problem. In the future, perhaps a forum dedicated to Python development would be more suited for these types of problems, as they are not ROS problems, but generic Python ones.